# Please how can I optimize the loading of data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The code have to fill Array with data from SQL-Server.
Then it write Array data to file.
Now it works, but is it  possibile to optimize my "For To Next". Because Counter can be realy big and this is not the only Array to fill with

```
For i = 0 To Counter
Dim PR = (SQL.RunReader("SELECT Requirement FROM Programme_Requirements
JOIN Specialities ON Specialities.Id_Speciality=Programme_Requirements.Id_Speciality AND Specialities.SpecialityName='" & SpecialityName(i) &
"' JOIN Educational_Levels ON Educational_Levels.Id_EducationalLevel=Programme_Requirements.Id_EducationalLevel AND 
Educational_Levels.EducationalLevel ='" & DocumentTypeId(i) &
"' JOIN Forms_of_Study ON Forms_of_Study.Id_FormofStudy=Programme_Requirements.Id_FormofStudy AND 
Forms_of_Study.FormofStudyName ='" & EducationFormName(i) & "'", "Requirement"))
Next
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample data?

Comment: Please learn how to parametrise your queries. SQL injection is not your friend.

Comment: Too broad question. You could create temporary table(s) from your array(s) and join your query(ies) to temporary table(s) - you don't save `for` cycles, but overall performance would likely be better.

Comment: It looks to me that several of your join clauses have parts that belong in a Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is happening in RunReader but try this...

```
Private Sub ProcessArrays()
        Dim strSQL =
        "SELECT Requirement FROM Programme_Requirements
        JOIN Specialities ON Specialities.Id_Speciality=Programme_Requirements.Id_Speciality 
        JOIN Educational_Levels ON Educational_Levels.Id_EducationalLevel=Programme_Requirements.Id_EducationalLevel 
        JOIN Forms_of_Study ON Forms_of_Study.Id_FormofStudy=Programme_Requirements.Id_FormofStudy 
        WHERE  Specialities.SpecialityName= @SpecialtyName
        AND 
        Educational_Levels.EducationalLevel = @DocumentType
        AND 
        Forms_of_Study.FormofStudyName = @EducationFormName;"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                cn.Open()
                For i As Integer = 0 To Counter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SpecialtyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SpecialtyName(i)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DocumentTypeId(i)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EducationFormName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EducationFormName(i)
                    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        'Use reader values
                    End Using
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I use parameters too. My question is more "Can I use something to not connect my database so much times?"  For now I have 6 array (like 'PR()') to fill from database using information that comes to me from another arrays (like 'SpecialityName()') and counter goes to 2000, so i use reader 12000 times now. I think I do it wrong, that i why I ask

Comment: In the above code the connection is opened only once outside the loop. There is only one connection to the database.